# Reducing file size of styled images

Tags: files, media

I always thought styled images are smaller than original ones in file size. So the main reason for styling was to reduce the file size. But today I noticed it isn't always the case. For example:

I downloaded an image `abcd.jpg` from facebook and then uploaded it to my Drupal website.

Originally the image was `405.3 kB` which is `2048px X 1536px`.

After downloading the same image from my drupal website the image is `698 kB` which is `1100px X 845px`.

```
Style Effect:(Scale width 1100)
```

And when I checked I found the same in most of the cases. Can anything be done about it without compromising image quality?

Answer (score 1):

It's in the nature of image compression that compressing an already compressed image can result in larger filesize. The image-toolkit (be it GD or image magick) can not know on what level the image is already compressed and will try to make the best of it (following the quality setting that No Sssweat describes). So you may want to try to set this to 100% to prevent repeated compression.

Further reading:

- [Efficient Image Resizing With ImageMagick](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick/)
- [In search of the most optimized image in Drupal 7](http://jimbir.ch/blog/search-most-optimized-image-drupal-7)

Answer (score 0):

You can always lower the image toolkit quality

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it will reduce image quality. Looking for something that does not compromise image quality.

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to use the reSmush.it image style optimizer module, see https://www.drupal.org/project/resmushit

It uses the eponymous service (see https://www.resmush.it/) which optimizes image size without affecting its quality. This optimization service is free (contrary to many other ones).